# rails associations & object identity: maintaining object identity through a series of changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`First of all, the fact that I am even asking this question implies that I am consciously choosing not to (strictly) obey the law of Demeter.

Since sometime (probably rails 3?) referring to `model.association.first` results in a new object each time, unless you use `.to_a` on the association:

```
campaign.campaign_shirts.first.to_s
=> "#<CampaignShirt:0x007fdd02c7fd58>"
campaign.campaign_shirts.first.to_s
=> "#<CampaignShirt:0x007fdd02ca6318>"
c.campaign_shirts.to_a.first.to_s
=> "#<CampaignShirt:0x007fdd02d13170>"
c.campaign_shirts.to_a.first.to_s
=> "#<CampaignShirt:0x007fdd02d13170>"
```

I've worked on several Rails 3/4 applications without even noticing this, probably because I do try to respect Demeter as much as is practical.

In this case I want Campaign to be in control, because it is a big state machine where many of its state changes involve transactionally coordinating changes in itself and various child objects.

Is there a way to freeze the association arrays at create and/or fetch time?

EDIT: I noticed almost immediately that they are frozen when you use `Campaign.includes(...).find`, which I am doing in my app. However I still have a problem in specs where the objects are factories created by FactoryGirl. Is there a way to say "freeze all the associations on this object" or do I have to call `.to_a` on each of them?

EDIT 2: I still have a problem when I refer to campaign through a `belongs_to` on user. (this seemed like a separate question, so I [asked it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132350/can-i-add-an-includes-extension-to-a-belongs-to-association)).
EDIT 3: the problem with the belongs_to includes extension was just syntax, so I'm removing the details of that.

So, my remaining problem is to get User.selected_campaign to act like it does in my app when it is built up by FactoryGirl. I'm going to try just doing a `.reload` at the start of each spec, which should trigger the includes extensions, at the cost of some spec performance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the (gory) details of your setup, but what if you just *memoize* `first` on the Campaign object?

```
def Campaign
  def first_campaign_shirt
    @first_campaign_shirt ||= campaign_shirts.first
  end
end
```

I think this way you obey the Law of Demeter again? But it might get annoying if you need more  *getters* than just `first_shirt`. So consider this just a suggestion that won't fit in a comment box. :)

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but if possible I would like to avoid adding memoization or other modifications to things Rails expects to be in control of, because it makes life difficult in the long-term for programmers like me who have a very short memory spa

Comment: also, I only used .first as an example to illustrate changing object id. I need all the objects to be frozen. I'd have to memoize the whole association, which rails already does if you call .to_a on it, or if the association was prefetched by an includes(..) clause.

Answer (score 0):

All of my in-app use cases were solved by carefully choosing where to add includes(..) to associations and scopes.

I was only able to solve the factory girl problem by calling reload on a factory object after creating it.