# can I add an includes extension to a belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having trouble getting a `belongs_to` association to eager load it's children. I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :campaigns, -> { includes :campaign_shirts, :arts, :selected_campaign_shirt }
  belongs_to :selected_campaign, {class_name: "Campaign", inverse_of: :user}, -> { includes :campaign_shirts, :arts, :selected_campaign_shirt }
end
```

which results in:

```
// GOOD
u.campaigns.first.campaign_shirts.first.to_s
=> "#<CampaignShirt:0x007fc023a9abb0>"
u.campaigns.first.campaign_shirts.first.to_s
=> "#<CampaignShirt:0x007fc023a9abb0>"

// NOT GOOD
u.selected_campaign.campaign_shirts.first.to_s
(queries db)
=> "#<CampaignShirt:0x007fc023d7c630>"
(queries db)
u.selected_campaign.campaign_shirts.first.to_s
=> "#<CampaignShirt:0x007fc01af528a0>"
```

Am I running afoul of [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2117)? Is there a way to achieve what I want, which is to be able to refer to `current_user.selected_campaign` and have eager-loaded/frozen `current_user.selected_campaign.campaign_shirts.first` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the lambda scope before other association options like follows:

```
# app/models/users.rb

belongs_to :selected_campaign, -> { includes :campaign_shirts, :arts, :selected_campaign_shirt }, {class_name: "Campaign", inverse_of: :user},
```